# Rails app: I need to build a json object from params inside a loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, loops

I need to build a json object inside a loop using params.

My params look like this...

```
params[:answers]
returns => {"1"=>"answer1", "2"=>"answer2"}
```

The keys in this json object are the id's of the survey question.

So I planed to loop through the keys to build the json object like this...

```
def build_answersheet_json(params[:answers], params[:survey_id])
  params[:answers].keys.each do |question_id|
    current_question = question_id
    current_answer = params[:answers][question_id]
  end
end
```

Since im using "t.json" in my migration to save json to postgres, I wanted to use the extracted question_id and answer to build a json object that looks something like this...

```
{
  survey_id: '1',
  answers: {
    question: [{
      question_id: 1,
      answer: 'answer1'
    }, {
      question_id: 2,
      answer: 'answer2'
      }]
  }
}
```

Ive been trying to do this using a method that looks somthing like this...

```
build_answersheet_json(params[:answers], params[:survey_id])
```

Ive tried JSON.parse() and Ive tried to just logically work through it but I cant seem to figure this out.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try something like that:

```
/* fake params (to test) */
params = {
    survey_id: '1',
    answers: {
        "1"=>"answer1", 
        "2"=>"answer2", 
        "3"=>"answer3", 
        "4"=>"answer4"
    }
}

def build_answersheet_json(answers, survey_id)
  {
    survey_id: survey_id,
    answers: answers.map { |k,v| { question_id: k.to_i, answer: v } }
  }
end


survey = build_answersheet_json(params[:answers], params[:survey_id])

puts survey.class 
#Hash

puts survey.to_json
# formated JSON string:
# {
#   "survey_id":"1",
#   "answers":[
#       {"question_id":1,"answer":"answer1"},
#       {"question_id":2,"answer":"answer2"},
#       {"question_id":3,"answer":"answer3"},
#       {"question_id":4,"answer":"answer4"}
#   ]
# }
```

In order to save to a `t.json` postgress column type, just pass the Hash `survey` object, like that:

```
YourModel.create(survey: survey)
```

Source: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html

Comment: This looks uber promising. Thanks for the quick reply. I have to hit the sack right now but I will run this through in the morning.

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly. Thanks for citing the article too!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
{
  survey: ¯\_༼◉ل͟◉༽_/¯,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Json may not be parsed if json have construction like this:

```
survey = {
}
```

Json may not contain `=` and assignment

Check real variables values with `puts varname.inspect` near at code lines where you meet unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Im sorry, the survey = {} should not be there. I just want the final object to look like what is after the " = "

I will edit the question.